# Laravel 5.2 Foreign Key fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to add a foreign key in my posts table to reference the id in the users table. Here are my migrations, the users table is the default one packed with laravel so the timestamps are from NOV 2014 however the posts is one I created. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot :)

**Users migration**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

**posts migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('section');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->date('post_created_date');
            $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned()->after('id');
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('posts');
    }
}
```

Every time I migrate I get the following error:

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating a table, you don't want to use `after` as it will create a syntax error.  Just place the column where you want it.  I believe `after` will only work for alter table statements.

```
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');  // Unsigned is assumed for increments so I removed that as well
        $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('section');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->date('post_created_date');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

Then in your model, you'd setup the relationship to your `users` table like so...

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id');
}
```

Feel free to rename the function however you want, I usually prefer to name it something that matches the foreign key.

Then you'd use it like `$post->author->name`.

Comment: As a further question if you don't mind, how do I access the users from the users table when I am echoing it out onto the page. I am trying {{ $post->author_id()->name }} but this throws an error. Is this something I do in the model?

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help @user3158900

Answer (score 2):

In your CreatePostsTable class, can you try this ?

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('section');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->date('post_created_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

   Schema::table('posts', function($table) {
       $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('users');
   });
}
```

Comment: As a further question if you don't mind, how do I access the users from the users table when I am echoing it out onto the page. I am trying {{ $post->author_id()->name }} but this throws an error. Is this something I do in the model?

Comment: You must define a relationship in your Model https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships. Then you'lle be able to call `{{ $post->author->name }}` :)